# Splitting strings with a regex

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am struggling to find out how I can achieve this.
Here is the content:

`"#1 Single" (2006) {Window Shopping (#1.2)}        UK:29 January 2006`

`"The Wright Stuff" (2000) {(#15.76)}           Germany:25 April 2011`

`Fever (2014/I)                     Brazil:26 February 2015 (Cinequest Film Festival)`

`Fever (2014/II)                        USA:June 2014`

Above is a variation of different strings, I have all of these strings in a `List<string>` and I only want the first part e.g. `The Wright Stuff` and the last part `Germany` `25 April 2011`. So if I had a `Dictionary<int,List<string>>` it would look like this:

```
new Dictionary<int, List<string>> {
    {
        1, new List<string>()
            {
                "The Wright Stuff",
                "Germany",
                "25 April 2011"
            }
        } 
    };
```

The above is what I want my outcome to be (Don't worry about the Dictionary's key, it is a GUID in my actual application).

But if the string has the extra bit on the end like `Fever (2014/I)                     Brazil:26 February 2015 (Cinequest Film Festival)` then I want the `(Cinequest Film Festival)` added too.

Can anyone assist me with this?

Comment: You tried string.Split(new[] { "  ", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) ? That way you could split the left and right part separated by many spaces and the parts separated by colons. You'd need to trim the results, but I think it get's close to what you want. Even without RegEx

Comment: Thats a good point, but if i split by `" "` it will split every word.

Comment: it's hardly visible in comments, but I added two spaces in the split, so you should only split between the parts and not between the words. The nice thing of this overload of Split() is that you can provide strings and not nessecarily just chars.

Comment: This doesn't remove all of the middle bit that I dont want though?

Comment: You're right, you'd need to clean up the first entry of the array, but this could be done with a simple Substring and IndexOf("("). That's 3 lines of code then to get the List<string> you want, I'm not sure, if you prefer a RegEx though and if this will be more efficient.

Comment: Can you post an answer with an example of the Substring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without using RegEx, this could be solved the following way (as discussed in the comments):

```
var theListOfString = yourInputString.Split(new[] { "  ", ":" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(p => p.Trim()).ToList();
theListOfString[0] = theListOfString[0].Substring(0, theListOfString[0].IndexOf("(") - 1);
```